# Running a script after reboot, but before login

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, cron

I am trying to notify myself whenever my PC reboots through a python script. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have tried Startup Applications and although it works, it runs my python script only after I login, which defeats the purpose. I have tried setting the following line in my crontab

```
@reboot /bin/reboot_script.sh
```

where reboot_script.sh bears the line `/usr/bin/python3 /bin/reboot_script.py`. I have tried adding `root` after `@reboot`, but nothing seems to work. My python file uses module `requests` to ping a server which notifies me of the reboot. When I run the program from the terminal after logging in, the notification is received and the code executes successfully.

What am I missing? Where should the file(s) be for it to run on reboot? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
The way I set crontab is by executing the following commands on the terminal.

```
sudo crontab > my-crontab
```

Add the above mentioned line at the end of the file. And then do

```
crontab my-crontab
```

EDIT2:
As per comments below, I added the following lines in a file named `reboot_notify.service` and placed it in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Notify on reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /bin/reboot_notify.py
```

Following this I ran `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl start reboot_notify.service` and `systemctl enable reboot_notify.service` as per the  answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1297889/1000921).

But even now the notification was received only after I logged in. What needs to be changed?

Comment: One option would be to [use a systemd service instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297887/crontab-reboot-is-not-working/1297889#1297889). This has generally worked better for me.

Comment: I agree with @Matigo. It’s not as difficult as it sounds using systemd and I’ve found it always works. Cron is fussy and can take time to diagnose as the learning curve is quite long

Comment: @PonJar I have updated the question with the method you pointed at. Is something missing? Many thanks.

Comment: @Matigo I have used your answer to update the question. Please let me know if some data is missing. Many thanks.

Comment: Be sure to have the service run as `root` by having `sudo` in front of your commands. Otherwise it will run only when your account signs in.

Comment: you should have something like `After=network.target` in the [Unit] section

Comment: @bac0n having that in [Unit], does it ensure my service runs after network is established?

Comment: Try systemd-analyze plot >bootup.svg and systemd-analyze critical-chain. You will be able to see the various targets in the systemd startup process.The plot command will generate an svg image file to view. I’d guess After=network.target is probably ok for your purpose but I’m not sure exactly what your script does.

Comment: You will also need to add `Before=gdm.service` under `[Unit]` but make sure that your script executes right or otherwise your login screen might be delayed considerably. Please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1175559/968501) for an example of a custom service that runs before login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your responses. I was able to fix it to send me a message before login, as soon as the machine restarted and network services came online. I have handled no network connection state in my python file and did not have to wait for network to be established for running the code. What have I done? Here are the exact steps.

1. Created a file by name `reboot_notify.service` on my Desktop.
2. Added the following content to my file (copied and edited from another service already in my system available at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Notify on reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /bin/reboot_notify.py
```

(The error in the question was that `python` did not exist in the directory.) I moved my python file to `/bin` and used `python-3.x`'s default install location. `ExecStart` is the command to be executed, you need to put the command you want to run here. Rest of the file is copied except for `Description`.

3. Moved the `.service` file from desktop to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`.
4. Ran `systemctl daemon-reload` for it to update the list of services.
5. Ran `systemctl start reboot_notify.service` to start the service. If there are any errors, you will get them here. You need to have no errors to proceed.
6. Ran `systemctl enable reboot_notify.service`. At this point the service got executed and I was notified by my setup.
7. Rebooted to check if it worked. It did. You can check the status of your service by running `systemctl status reboot_notify.service`.

Many thanks to @[Matigo](https://askubuntu.com/users/1091774/matigo) for his comment which helped me make this work.